# How to debug windows service OnSessionChange Event

Tags: .net, debugging, session, windows-services

I have a windows service and i want to see what happens when the user logs on or off, signs out etc..I have placed a `Debugger.Launch` inside the override of `OnSessionChange` but it does not fire.

How can i debug that part of code ?

```
public class MyService:ServiceBase
{
     protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription) {
         Debugger.Launch();  //debugger does not fire here !
      }
    protected override void OnStart(){ } //debugger fires here
    protected override void OnStop(){ }  //debugger fires here
}
```

**P.S**
I am expecting when  i unlock the computer , the event to fire and to get in visual studio with the debugger.Is there any way to debug it  or the logs are the only way to see what happens there ?

Comment: Have you - "*You must set the CanHandleSessionChangeEvent property to true to enable the execution of this method.*"

Comment: Thank you very much it worked ! You can post a reply i will accept it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`CanHandleSessionChangeEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canhandlesessionchangeevent?view=netframework-4.8) property to `true` to enable sinking of that event.